# PDFBOX 2.0+ java flatten annotations freetext created by foxit

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I ran into a very tough issue.  We have forms that were supposed to be filled out, but some people used annotation freeform text comments in foxit instead of filling the form fields, so the annotations never flatten.  When our render software generates the final document annotations are not included.

The solution I tried is to basically go through the document, get the annotation text content and write it to the pdf so it is on the final document then remove the actual annotation, but I run into an issue where I don't know the font the annotation is using, line space, etc so cannot find out how to get it from a pdfbox to recreate exacactly as the annotation looks on the unflattened form.
Basically I want to flatten annotatations that are freeform created in foxit (The typewriter comment feature)
  Here is the code.  It is working, but again I am struggling with figuring out how to get the annotations to write to my final pdf document. Again flatten on the acroform is not working because these are not acroform fields!  The live code filters out anything that is not a freetext type annotation, but below code should show my issue.

```
    public static void main(String [] args)
{
        String startDoc = "C:/test2/test.pdf";
     String  finalFlat = "C:/test2/test_FLAT.pdf";

    try {
        // for testing
        try {
            //BasicConfigurator.configure();
            File myFile = new File(startDoc);
            PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load( myFile );
            PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
            PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm();

            // set the NeedApperances flag
            pdAcroForm.setNeedAppearances(false);

            // correct the missing page link for the annotations
            for (PDPage page : pdDoc.getPages()) {

                for (PDAnnotation annot : page.getAnnotations()) {
                    System.out.println(annot.getContents());
                    System.out.println(annot.isPrinted());
                    System.out.println(annot.isLocked());

                    System.out.println(annot.getAppearance().toString());
                    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDoc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND,true,true);
                    int fontHeight = 14; 
                    contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, fontHeight);

                    float height = annot.getRectangle().getLowerLeftY();

                    String s  = annot.getContents().replaceAll("\t", "    ");

                    String ss[] = s.split("\\r");
                    for(String sss : ss)
                    {
                        contentStream.beginText();  
                        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(annot.getRectangle().getLowerLeftX(),height );
                      contentStream.showText(sss);
                      height = height + fontHeight * 2 ;

                      contentStream.endText();
                    }
                      contentStream.close();
                    page.getAnnotations().remove(annot);                    
                }
            }               
            pdAcroForm.flatten();
            pdDoc.save(finalFlat);
            pdDoc.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have a look at the default appearance, call getDefaultAppearance() to get it. That one has a font name which can be looked up in the resources of the appearance stream or in the Acroform default resources. What might help is to look at the source code of PDTextAppearanceHandler and PDFreeTextAppearanceHandler. This will probably not be easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I am a novice and having a hard time with this one.  If you have any sample code, or even better i saw someone mention they can render the appearance and write to pdf which i saw was possible, but so far no luck.

Comment: No, what I have is the source code of PDFBox itself, this shows how it was done to handle these annotation - the appearance streams are itself content streams. I think it should be possible to reuse this code to add it to the page content stream. Another idea is to change PDFBox itself in PDAcroform.flatten() to flatten all annotations, not just the widget annotations. Search for "preserve all non widget annotations" and "widgetsForPageMap" in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not a fun one.  After a million different tests, and I STILL do not understand all the nuances, but this is the version that appeas to flatten all pdf files and annotations if they are visible on PDF.  Tested about half a dozen pdf creators and if an annotation is visible on a page this hopefully flattens it.  I suspect there is a better way by pulling the matrix and transforming it and what not, but this is the only way I got it to work everywhere.

```
public static void flattenv3(String startDoc, String endDoc) {

  org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO);
  String finalFlat = endDoc;


  try {

   try {
    //BasicConfigurator.configure();
    File myFile = new File(startDoc);
    PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(myFile);
    PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm();

    if (pdAcroForm != null) {
     pdAcroForm.setNeedAppearances(false);
     pdAcroForm.flatten();
    }

    // set the NeedApperances flag

    boolean isContentStreamWrapped;
    int ii = 0;

    for (PDPage page: pdDoc.getPages()) {
     PDPageContentStream contentStream;
     isContentStreamWrapped = false;
     List < PDAnnotation > annotations = new ArrayList < > ();

     for (PDAnnotation annotation: page.getAnnotations()) {



      if (!annotation.isInvisible() && !annotation.isHidden() && annotation.getNormalAppearanceStream() != null)

      {
       ii++;
       if (ii > 1) {
        // contentStream.close();
        // continue;

       }


       if (!isContentStreamWrapped) {
        contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDoc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
        isContentStreamWrapped = true;
       } else {
        contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDoc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true);
       }

       PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = annotation.getNormalAppearanceStream();

       PDFormXObject fieldObject = new PDFormXObject(appearanceStream.getCOSObject());

       contentStream.saveGraphicsState();


       boolean needsTranslation = resolveNeedsTranslation(appearanceStream);



       Matrix transformationMatrix = new Matrix();
       boolean transformed = false;

        float lowerLeftX = annotation.getNormalAppearanceStream().getBBox().getLowerLeftX();
        float lowerLeftY = annotation.getNormalAppearanceStream().getBBox().getLowerLeftY();
        PDRectangle bbox = appearanceStream.getBBox();
        PDRectangle fieldRect = annotation.getRectangle();

        float xScale = fieldRect.getWidth() - bbox.getWidth();

        transformed = true;

        lowerLeftX = fieldRect.getLowerLeftX();
        lowerLeftY = fieldRect.getLowerLeftY();
        if (bbox.getLowerLeftX() <= 0 && bbox.getLowerLeftY() < 0 && Math.abs(xScale) < 1) //BASICALLY EQUAL TO 0 WITH ROUNDING
        {


         lowerLeftY = fieldRect.getLowerLeftY() - bbox.getLowerLeftY();
         if (bbox.getLowerLeftX() < 0 && bbox.getLowerLeftY() < 0) //THis is for the o
         {

          lowerLeftX = lowerLeftX - bbox.getLowerLeftX(); 

         }

        } else if (bbox.getLowerLeftX() == 0 && bbox.getLowerLeftY() < 0 && xScale >= 0) {

         lowerLeftX = fieldRect.getUpperRightX();

        } else if (bbox.getLowerLeftY() <= 0 && xScale >= 0) {

         lowerLeftY = fieldRect.getLowerLeftY() - bbox.getLowerLeftY() - xScale;

        } else if (bbox.getUpperRightY() <= 0) {

         if (annotation.getNormalAppearanceStream().getMatrix().getShearY() < 0) {
          lowerLeftY = fieldRect.getUpperRightY();
          lowerLeftX = fieldRect.getUpperRightX();

         }

        } else {

        }



        transformationMatrix.translate(lowerLeftX,
         lowerLeftY);
        contentStream.transform(transformationMatrix);


       contentStream.drawForm(fieldObject);
       contentStream.restoreGraphicsState();
       contentStream.close();
      }
     }
     page.setAnnotations(annotations);
    }


    pdDoc.save(finalFlat);
    pdDoc.close();
    File file = new File(finalFlat);

    // Desktop.getDesktop().browse(file.toURI());


   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
  }
 }
```

}

Comment: The method `resolveNeedsTranslation` is missing from your code, isn't it?

Comment: The code is written where that function shouldnt be required, but if you have am example where the code produces incorrect results i would def want to correct this code.   The form is flattened first where that is evaluatwd, then then annotations are itterated, so i think it takes care of both scenerios.

Comment: Well, if *that function shouldnt be required*, you shouldn't need to call it from your code but you do.

Comment: It shouldnt be included, it was copied from a prior version of the code that had it, And there is other items that can be cleaned up as well, i just wanted to update this with what is working and help someone else that had an issue.    Once i flattened form annotations it always returned the same so it became an orphaned boolean since i found no examples that made that a usable boolean.  I stress this code has worked for all pdfs i checked, i do not claim it is not flawed, but it works much better than any other examples i have found online!:)