# PDFBox - Prevent annotations appearing on top of overlay

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am overlaying a pdf on another pdf.
The issue I'm experiencing is the "background" pdf annotations are floating above the "foreground" page.

Is there a way to flatten or prevent the annotation from floating above the overlay?
Here's an example: The black text should be overlaying the red comment block.

[image: text should be overlaying the square]

The code I'm using:

```
    PDDocument baseDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("examples/test/base.pdf"));;
    PDDocument overlayDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("examples/test/overlay.pdf"));

    Iterator<PDPage> baseDocumentIterator = baseDocument.getPages().iterator();
    Iterator<PDPage> overlayIterator = overlayDocument.getPages().iterator();

    while(baseDocumentIterator.hasNext() && overlayIterator.hasNext()) {
        PDPage backing = baseDocumentIterator.next();
        List<PDAnnotation> annotations = backing.getAnnotations();
        for (PDAnnotation a :annotations) {
            a.setLocked(true);
            a.setReadOnly(true);
        }
    }

    PDAcroForm acroForm = baseDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    if (acroForm != null) {
        acroForm.flatten();
    }
    Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
    overlay.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.FOREGROUND);
    overlay.setInputPDF(baseDocument);
    overlay.setAllPagesOverlayPDF(overlayDocument);

    Map<Integer, String> ovmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    overlay.overlay(ovmap);

    AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission();
    ap.setCanExtractContent(false);
    ap.setCanFillInForm(false);
    ap.setCanModify(false);
    ap.setReadOnly();
    ap.setCanModifyAnnotations(false);
    StandardProtectionPolicy standardPP = new StandardProtectionPolicy("", "", ap);
    standardPP.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
    baseDocument.protect(standardPP);
    baseDocument.save("examples/test/output.pdf");
    baseDocument.close();
    overlayDocument.close();
```

Is there anything I can do to get the comment block appearing behind the overlay?

[Example pdfs](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1l59aUPZtEJQmojVVe0HaR54M-m32Zicq)

Comment: *"Is there anything I can do to get the comment block appearing behind the overlay?"* - You indeed have to flatten the annotations into the page content before overlaying the PDF because annotation always are above the page content. [This recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61127801/1729265) might develop into annotation flattening code but it currently appears to be work-in-progress...